# Typescript: Create an interface or the narrowest type from an Object

Tags: typescript, types, casting

Is there a way to create an interface or a narrow type from an object?

For example I would like something like:

```
const obj : someType = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: {
    c: "c"
  }
};

type myType = narrowTypeOf obj
```

Whereas `myType` should then result into:

```
{
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: {
    c: string
  }
};
```

Sadly (or better fortunately) the build in `type mytype = typeof obj` would result into `someType`, since I did already declare it to be of that type.

If there is a way to use an object as a parameter to a type definition - that would solve my problem aswell.

Comment: Just don't cast it as something it isn't. `typeof obj` should work.

Comment: The Problem is not casting it as something it isn't. Its casting it at all. If I were to cast it to someType = { [key: string]: string | someType } - that would not be false. Still typeof would (rigtly) retrun 'sometype'.  As a workaround I currently do not cast it at all - but that does not spark joy! Still many thanks for the answer!

Comment: You should always let TS infer types, so it *should* spark joy!

Comment: Do you say there is no way to retreave the infered type, after it is alredy declared to be a broader type, or do you just not think it is a good idea?

Comment: I'm just saying you shouldn't type it as anything broader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `SomeType` is specifically a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) in which one of the members is the narrow type you want, this isn't going to work.  Let's first look at the happy case where `SomeType` *is* such a union, even though apparently that's not your use case:

```
type SomeType = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: {
    c: string
  }
} | { foo: string } | { bar: string };
```

Here `SomeType` is explicitly the union of the type you want and two unrelated types.  Then when you assign a value to `obj` annotated as `SomeType`,

```
const obj: SomeType = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: {
    c: "c"
  }
};
```

the type `typeof obj` captured at this point is the type you want:

```
type MyType = typeof obj;
/* type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: {
        c: string;
    };
} */
```

The type `MyType` does not contain `{foo: string}` or `{bar: string}`.  That's because the compiler uses [control flow based type analysis](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to narrow union types upon assignment (see [microsoft/TypeScript#8010](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) for the PR notes implementing this).

But there is no control flow based narrowing of *non-union* typed variables upon assignment.  At one point the TS team seemed to be [considering it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513#issuecomment-217871478), and there's an open suggestion (see [microsoft/TypeScript#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976)) for control flow narrowing of non-union types, but for now it's just not part of the language.

That means if your `SomeType` is just wider than you'd like but not specifically a union containing the element, you're stuck.  Once you annotate a variable to be that wide type, all assignments to that variable will forget anything more specific about the current value of that type.

---

The right thing to do here is *not* to annotate the variable's type.  The only reason why you should annotate a variable as a wider type than that of the value you assign is if you want to mutate the variable's contents later to make it some other inhabitant of that wider type. For example, if `SomeType` is given as this:

```
interface SomeType {
  a: string | number;
  b: unknown;
  c: object;
}
```

Then the only good reason why you would annotate the following declaration as `SomeType`:

```
const obj: SomeType = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: {
    c: "c"
  }
};
```

Would be if you planned to do this later:

```
obj.a = 123;
obj.b = () => 456;
obj.c = [789];
```

---

Assuming you are not planning to need that wider type, then you should let the compiler *infer* the type of `obj`. If you are concerned that this will let you assign something *incompatible* with `SomeType`, then you can use a helper function which acts sort of like a narrowing annotation:

```
const annotateAs = <T>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u;
```

This helper function can be used like this:

```
const asSomeType = annotateAs<SomeType>();
```

Now `asSomeType()` is a function which will return its input without widening, but will give an error if that input cannot be assigned to `SomeType`:

```
const oops = asSomeType({
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c" // error! string is not an object
})
```

Now you can write the `obj` assignment like this:

```
const obj = asSomeType({
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: {
    c: "c"
  }
});
```

That succeeded, so `obj` is definitely a `SomeType`, but now the type of `obj` is:

```
type MyType = typeof obj;
/* type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: {
        c: string;
    };
} */
```

as you wanted.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-JFAx5hjJ8pBQsIBOEIpEEtGY7F4iJIGrmYmk8kOG786l54DY5MQACCUBlAB4+LrtXqkL2KEgIAAPb7AAAmPYHGrQUgoOqE+rQJ1iwHiICg2b6rfbXy7UF7+4gg61bpiLa8MB7Il3541udyBQqBk53JrdQaSAD46yLItCyAAhEcVh-D27atrS9aNlq4pbvExIyk+DLgi+kKsh+JR1N+uzVAcAoNE0CHXqwwbzAePrDMS-rTB61HCKmLIQdsSyaKEaycXsnH8txHEHGKdhIJc1wEPYQA)